# Get tags from div with checkboxes and the result is THE DIV's CONTAINING ALL THE TAGS inside...if not don't show them?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, filter, tags

I like to find out how I can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/asjbak/69WL3/
with checkboxes instead of the textfield.
I tried it with push and to combine it with this example: http://jsfiddle.net/3qwty/8/
The above example shows every div that has 1 of the tags inside.

In the example with the textfield it shows just the div's with all the tags.

Is there some way I can push the textfield by clicking on the checkboxes or is it even possible without a textbox??

Hope one of you folks have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure what you are asking for but it looks like you are trying to merge the functionality of the 2 fiddles, and I've done what you've asked for in the first sentence.

You can try a contains to find the presence of a string in element text. Id probably do your tags in the class so you can do 'hasClass' instead, rather than showing everything at the beginning and hiding on a not found in string basis, therefore adding more logic.

Check it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/YSL9T/13/

Comment: Yes.......exactly what I wanted! I think you're going to make a lot of people very happy with your answer. I couldn't find it anywere! +10 kudo's!

Comment: Don't have enough reputation but when I get them I'll use them for this answer!